# How to get url/href from XML table cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, xmlhttprequest

I am having difficulties getting the url/href from an XML cell.

In the example below I am able to get the values of **type** and **subtype** but I don't know how to get the **url** from **photo**.

My thought was that it could work similar to this ***"var x = elem.getElementsByTagName("photo").url;"*** but it seems I can't figure it out.

XML:

```
<item>
    <type>animal</type>
    <subtype>dog</contentId>
    <photo url="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/15/46/dog-1210559_1280.jpg"/>
</item>

<item>
    <type>animal</type>
    <subtype>cat</contentId>
    <photo url="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg"/>
</item>
```

Code:

```
<style>
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>


<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Load</button>
<br><br>
<table id="myTable"></table>


<script>
var xmlFile = 'file.xml';

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.open("GET", xmlFile, true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      xmlFunction(this.response);
    }
  };

}

function xmlFunction(xml) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
  var table = "<tr><th>Type</th><th>Subtype</th><th>Photo</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
  for (var elem of x) {
    var type = elem.getElementsByTagName(
  "type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var subtype = elem.getElementsByTagName("subtype")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var photo = elem.getElementsByTagName("photo").url;

    table += "<tr><td>" + type + "</td><td>" + subtype + "</td><td>" + photo + "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have this line:

```
var photo = elem.getElementsByTagName("photo").url;
```

You want the attribute from the element instead. Since you are using 0 as the indices, you could also use that for the phote and you might update that line of code to:

```
var photo = elem.getElementsByTagName("photo")[0].getAttribute('url');
```

**Note** that in the xml you provided, this line is not ok:

```
<subtype>dog</contentId>
```

You are also missing a root node, but I assume this is xml might be part of a larger part.

Comment: You are absolutely awesome, it worked great! :) Thanks a lot! And thanks for pointing out the other issues as well, fortunately I just forgot to rename that cell when I copied it to SO, but I am prone to making mistakes so I'm glad you also mentioned it.